# scala code can be ran in command line but eclipse

Tags: scala, sbt

```
import com.twitter.finagle.{Http, Service}
import com.twitter.util.{Await, Future}
import java.net.InetSocketAddress
import org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.http._

object Client extends App {
//#builder
  val client: Service[HttpRequest, HttpResponse] =
    Http.newService("www.google.com:80")
//#builder
//#dispatch
  val request =  new DefaultHttpRequest(
    HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1, HttpMethod.GET, "/")
  val response: Future[HttpResponse] = client(request)
//#dispatch
//#callback
  response onSuccess { resp: HttpResponse =>
    println("GET success: " + resp)
  }
  Await.ready(response)
//#callback
}
```

I have this code 
when I run it from command line, it works

```
./sbt 'run-main Proxy'
```

But when I run it from scala ide(eclipse)
it gave me

```
Error: Could not find or load main class Server
```

why is that? how can I fix this?
thanks

Comment: Are you running a configuration that's set up to run a class called `Server`?

Comment: @ChrisMartin yes I did

Comment: Do you have a class called `Server`?

Comment: no i don't, but why I can run it from command line "sbt run-main Server"

Comment: This is a question about SBT, then?